# Is "equivalent" functions / methods readability worth its maintanability cost?

Tags: api-design, clean-code, readability, maintainability

First of all, I am sorry if it is a duplicate, I could not think of any "correct" wording to search about this.

Second let me clarify: By "equivalent" I mean methods that are meant to have the same behavior, either because api design or other reason.

An example of this is the Java [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Deque.html) interface (or ArrayDeque if you want to talk about an implementation).

It extends the `Collection` and `Queue` interfaces, but also declares it's own methods for (what I believe is) readability and "disambiguity" sake. The Java Docs have the following:

> Comparison of Queue and Deque methods
>
> Queue Method > Equivalent Deque Method
>
> add(e) -> addLast(e)
> offer(e) -> offerLast(e)
> remove() -> removeFirst()
> poll() -> pollFirst()
> element() -> getFirst()
> peek() -> peekFirst()

Now to my question:

I have a similar situation where I need to extend an third party interface, but the naming used in that interface can get ambiguous in my new interface context.

My question boils down to the following: are "equivalent" methods / functions worth it's cost? For example when writing tests, I would need to do (in Deque example):

```
@Test
void testAddLast(){ ... }

@Test
void testAddAndAddLastEquivalence(){ ... }
```

and then add a similar delegation boilerplate to the implementations.

I am thinking about just writing documentation and let go of the more legible "equivalent" method.

Is there a consensus about trading readability for maintainability in coding pratices in this cases or is this too broad?

Comment: If you consider documentation to be sufficient, why bother resolving the ambiguity by introducing new methods? Why not stick with the original interface and simply document the meaning of each method in the new context?

Comment: No, there is no "general consensus". This depends 100% on the situation, and even then the decision is probably opinionated. It will also make a difference who the "audience" for the API is, if you are just targeting your internal 5 person dev team, or if you are targeting 500.000 potential users of your library.

Comment: @null that is exactly what I am considering. The "equivalent" methods are more of a "syntatic sugar" than a real need. But I am asking this question nonetheless to see if what I am doing can be considered a bad pratice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for creating these equivalent methods is one of **naming**, and is therefore of a **documentative** nature.

There are no hard and fast rules for documentation, as this is a very subjective concept, defined by nothing else than "it helps humans understand better". The very nature of the field of education proves how you're not able to enshrine that approach into a universal blanket one-size-fits-all solution.

> My question boils down to the following: are "equivalent" methods / functions worth it's cost?

That very much depends on how much added value the consumers of your code get from it. This is not answerable without considering both the specific naming involved, how established these names are and if there are niche context-specific meanings attached to them, and who is consuming your code.

> I am thinking about just writing documentation and let go of the more legible "equivalent" method.

That is certainly one way to go. But since you're interested in general consensus, it is generally agreed upon that self-documenting readable code is preferred over having to read a document before understanding the syntax.

Making these equivalent functions is definitely a notch in the direction of having self-documenting code, **assuming** that the new name is intuitively understood and the old name wasn't (as much).

> Is there a consensus about trading readability for maintainability in coding practices

You can definitely minimize the maintainability cost, since you're dealing with an identical wrapper. By having one method blindly call the other, there's little maintenance cost involved. Should the signature of the original method ever change (which shouldn't be often if this is a library), the related wrapper method will have a compiler error, so it's easy to realize that this needs to change

You're right that it's still a non-zero cost, but whether that cost outweighs the cost of developer confusion very much depends on (like I said before) the specific improvement you're making and whether it actually helps the people who end up consuming and/or reading your code.

While good practice coding is often justified using "on average" cost/benefit analyses (which why you're asking this question, I suspect), this is not as easy to do for documentative practices, as this is a wholly subjective consideration fully rooted in its specific context.